# Dart. In a new MAP, using polymer, why do I get "too many elements"?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

In Dart, I create a new map, and examine it under debug. In a Dart console app, there is no problem.

In a newly-created polymer app and examine it under debug, I get the following subtree:

```
>mymap                               {}
   >_data
   >_index
     >_buffer
     >_iterator
     >_reversed
     >_runtimetype
     >_single                        Bad State: Too many elements [id=114]
```

Should I be worried about it; is it safe to ignore it?

cheers

Steve

Comment: Examine it under debug does mean what? (DartEditor debugger, Dartium devtools, Webstorm debugger, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in the tool you are using.

Comment: Hi, I am use the Dart Editor. I put in a break point immediately after Map mup = new Map(). The "bad state" can be seen in the map structure.

Comment: Never heard or seen such a problem but it seems a problem with DartEditor not with Polymer. DartEditor is discontinued btw.

Comment: Oh!!  But I can still download it here - https://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/.  What would replace it? What do you use?

Comment: The next Dart version will not include DartEditor anymore.
WebStorm is the recommended replacement and I use it as well. But you can use Sublime, Eclipse, Vim, ... I think IntelliJ (similar to WebStorm) provides a community edition (lacks proper debugging support AFAIK, as does Sublime). Dart Eclipse plugin has some issues on Windows (with symlinks) where a fix is work-in-progress (getting rid of symlinks entirely).

Comment: Thank you Gunter. Most helpful, as usual!